# How to position excel chart using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I am developing a excel chart programmatically using c# and excel interop dll.
I develop this kind of chart. here is the screen shot

[image]

But i want chart like..(New Chart)

[image]

Here i am giving my full code. please see to it and guide me what extra code i need to make new chart.

Excel Data..

[image]

```
Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Excel.ChartObject myChart;
Excel.Range chartRange;
Excel.Chart chartPage;
myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(630, 20, 300, 250);
chartRange = xlWorkSheet.Range["AW2", "BA5"];
chartPage = myChart.Chart;    
chartPage.Legend.Delete();                        
myChart.Height = 380;
myChart.Width = 565;
myChart.Chart.HasDataTable = true;
myChart.Chart.DataTable.Font.Size = 10;
myChart.Chart.DataTable.Font.Name = "+Body";
chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlLineMarkers;
```

Comment: In this i solved below portion called as DataTable by changing chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue); line to chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, Excel.XlRowCol.xlColumns); . But now also i am not able to display the right side axis. Please give any idea about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem. Now just add some lines of code in above given code. Call this function `chart_series_design(chartPage, "", "");` at the end. Function is like

```
public void chart_series_design(Excel.Chart chartPage,string xmsg,string ymsg)
        {
            chartPage.set_HasAxis(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary, true);
            chartPage.set_HasAxis(Excel.XlAxisType.xlSeriesAxis, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary, true);
            chartPage.set_HasAxis(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary, true);
            chartPage.set_HasAxis(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary, true);
            chartPage.set_HasAxis(Excel.XlAxisType.xlSeriesAxis, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary, true);
            chartPage.set_HasAxis(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary, true);


            Excel.Series series = (Excel.Series)chartPage.SeriesCollection(1);
            series.AxisGroup = Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary;
            series.AxisGroup = Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary;

            series.Format.Line.Weight = 1.0F;
            series.Format.Line.Visible = MsoTriState.msoFalse;  //Tri-State 
            series.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = (int)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbWhite;


            series = (Excel.Series)chartPage.SeriesCollection(2);
            series.AxisGroup = Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary;
            series.AxisGroup = Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary;
            series.Format.Line.Weight = 1.0F;
            series.Format.Line.Visible = MsoTriState.msoFalse;  //Tri-State 
            series.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = (int)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbWhite;

            series = (Excel.Series)chartPage.SeriesCollection(3);
            series.AxisGroup = Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary;
            series.AxisGroup = Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary;
            series.Format.Line.Weight = 1.0F;
            series.Format.Line.Visible = MsoTriState.msoFalse;  //Tri-State 
            series.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = (int)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbWhite;

            series = (Excel.Series)chartPage.SeriesCollection(4);
            series.AxisGroup = Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary;
            series.AxisGroup = Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary;
            series.Format.Line.Weight = 1.0F;
            series.Format.Line.Visible = MsoTriState.msoFalse;  //Tri-State 
            series.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = (int)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbWhite;


            Excel.Axis axis;
            axis = (Excel.Axis)chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
            axis.HasTitle = true;
            axis.AxisTitle.Text = xmsg;

            axis = (Excel.Axis)chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
            axis.HasTitle = true;
            axis.AxisTitle.Text = ymsg;


        }
```